# How to build a Scala project whose dependency is no longer available via repository?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to build a legacy Scala project which depends on these:

- `sbt-twirl 1.0.2`
- `sbt-native-packager 0.7.4`
- `sbt-js-engine 1.0.1`
- `sbt-webdriver 1.0.0`

However, it seems these are no longer available via repositories like Maven Central.

How is it possible to build the project? As the purpose is to build the project *as it is* as possible, upgrading the dependencies is the last resort (because it will require much work if the dependencies introduce any breaking changes in newer versions).

Comment: Plugins haven't always been published to Maven Central. Did you configure https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases or https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases for instance?

Comment: Perhaps default repositories changed, maybe it was caused by Bintray changes and forced migration, or maybe someone had Bintray added in some global config but the first plugin from the list is there https://scala.jfrog.io/ui/native/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-twirl/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.0.2/